# How to convert equation of a plane into an equivalent coordinate transformation?

Tags: geometry, rotations

Let $\hat{\mathbf{x}}, \hat{\mathbf{y}},\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ be the unit vectors defining my 'world' coordinates.

Consider the following: 
[image]

In this example, 
$$\mathbf{r}_1 = r_{1,x} \hat{\mathbf{x}} + r_{1,y} \hat{\mathbf{y}} +  r_{1,z} \hat{\mathbf{z}} $$

and the equation for the plane is, for a normal vector $\mathbf{n} = (n_1,n_2,n_3)$,

$$n_1 (x-r_{1,x})+n_2 (y-r_{1,y}) + n_3 (z-r_{1,z})=0$$

I've defined the plane where this circle lives.

**The problem is, I don't want an equation of a plane, but instead a transformation of my initial coordiante system into a new one.**

I want to define a coordinate system $\hat{\mathbf{x}}', \hat{\mathbf{y}}',\hat{\mathbf{z}}'$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$ that's rotated such that,

$$n_1 (x-r_{1,x})+n_2 (z-r_{1,y}) + n_3 (z-r_{1,z})=0$$

lives in the $\hat{\mathbf{x}}', \hat{\mathbf{y}}'$ plane. That way, I can use the $\hat{\mathbf{x}}', \hat{\mathbf{y}}'$ plane to define a circle but can treat it like a standard 2D plane with polar coordinates.

How do I do this? I'm particularly confused given that I gather rotation and translation aren't necessarily commutative, so I'm confused how to do this.

Comment: Also, in your equation for the plane, did you probably mean $n_2(y-r_{1,y})$ for the second term?

Comment: @Nick i think i cleaned it up

Comment: @amd corrected it

Comment: Do you really need a new coordinate system? If you simply want to parameterize the circle, you can use $\mathbf r + \mathbf v_1 \cos\theta + (\mathbf n\times\mathbf v_1)\sin\theta$, where $\mathbf n$ is a _unit_ normal to the plane and $\mathbf v_1$ is, as pictured, the vector from $\mathbf r$ to any point on the circle, i.e., a vector parallel to the plane and having length equal to the circle’s radius.

Comment: @amd I am working in an applied context in which picking a normal vector precisely will be harder to measure than the angles. Therefore it would be easier to work with rotational matrices and I would prefer an answer that dealt with that specifically. However, I found the cross product approach taken by you and Nick to be very helpful and informative so I would leave that information here as it seems pertinent to the question.

Comment: Per your question, you already have a normal to the plane. Constructing a rotation matrix involves computing that normal one way or another, so I don’t think you’re any better off doing that. On the other hand, once you have the normal, finding a vector orthogonal to it involves a trivial element swap.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to find a basis of the plane you are interested in. First find any vector $\mathbf{v}$ in your plane, which can be anything orthogonal to $\mathbf{n} = \left(\begin{array}{c}n_1 \\ n_2 \\ n_3 \end{array} \right)$. You should choose it to have length 1 to make things easier. We will use this as your new $\hat{\mathbf{x}}'$, which will point along the $x$-axis in your new reference plane.

To find your $\hat{\mathbf{y}}'$, simply take the cross product $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{n}$. This is guaranteed to be orthogonal to both $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ by standard properties of the cross product. Being orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$ means it also lives in your plane. You should again rescale so it has length 1.

Then $\hat{\mathbf{z}}'$ will just be $\mathbf{n}$ itself (or rather the unit vector pointing in the direction of $\mathbf{n}$), since it already points "up" relative to your plane.

Now form the matrix $A$ whose columns are $\hat{\mathbf{x}}'$, $\hat{\mathbf{y}}'$, and $\hat{\mathbf{z}}'$. This matrix will send $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ to $\hat{\mathbf{x}}'$, and so on... This sends the $x,y$ plane to the plane through the origin that is parallel to your desired plane. Finally, you simply add $\mathbf{r}$ to translate everything away from the origin.

Summary: if you have a vector $\mathbf{a} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{array} \right)$ in the $x,y$-plane, then the corresponding point in your new plane will be $A \, \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{r}$.

Comment: But the plane is not orthogonal to $\mathbf{r}$. doesn’t that mean if i choose a $\mathbf{v}$ in my plane that it wont be orthogonal to $\mathbf{r}$?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will modify my post.

Comment: I fixed it. It should have been the vector $\mathbf{n}$, not $\mathbf{r}$. Good catch.